# Proper design pattern for 202 Accepted responses

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, celery-task

I have a celery `shared_task` setup to retry up to 10 times if it doesn't succeed the first time. The initial log statement is only executed once. None of the exceptions ever get raised nor does the embedded `try/else`. The statement `result = LdapHostGroupView().start(data, username, version)` does execute and it shows from log entries that it succeeded, but the final `else` never executes.

What's going on here?

```
@shared_task(bind=True, default_retry_delay=15, max_retry=10)
def host_accepted(self, data, username, version):
    from .api.views import LdapHostGroupView
    name = data.get('name', '')
    version = Decimal(version)
    log.debug("name: %s, version: %s, version type: %s, data: %s",
              name, version, type(version), data)

    try:
        obj = Transaction.objects.get(endpoint_name=name)
    except Transaction.DoesNotExist as e:
        msg = "Could not find transaction '{}'".format(name)
        log.critical(msg)
        syslog.critical(msg)
    else:
        try:
            result = LdapHostGroupView().start(data, username, version)
        except RealmBundleDoesNotExist as e:
            log.debug("Bundle does not exist yet.")
            obj.job_summary += str(e) + '\n'
            obj.job_status = Transaction.INPROGRESS
            obj.save()
            self.retry(exc=e) # ** self.request.retries)
        except (RealmCriticalException, ValidationError) as e:
            error = e.get_full_details()
            log.debug("Host Accepted error: %s", error)

            if isinstance(error, dict):
                for field, values in error.items():
                    for value in values:
                        ed = value.get('message')

                        if isinstance(ed, ErrorDetail):
                            item = str(ed)
                        else:
                            item = value

                        msg = "Field '{}' has error: {}\n".format(field, item)
                        obj.job_summary += msg
            else:
                obj.job_summary += "Had error with no message.\n"

            obj.job_status = Transaction.FAILURE
            obj.save()
        else:
            log.info("Celery task 'host_accepted' executed at %s, "
                     "returned %s, incoming data %s",
                     datetime.now(tzutc()).isoformat(), result, data)

            # Check the result object.

            obj.job_status = Transaction.SUCCESS
            obj.save()
```

it is called in the Django view like this:

```
   host_accepted.delay(request.data, request.user.username, request.version)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it occurred to me after posting my question that my code above was relying on me being able to either recreate a `request` object or to pickle one. Neither of these approaches was possible. So what I needed to do was to wrap only the piece of code that would take a while to run in a celery task. I found that I could return the result of a celery task in the serializer's `create` method instead of the normal DB object.

I should mention that this serializer never returns a DB object in any case since it actually aggregates data from two external APIs into my API. I don't show that code.

My views have been heavily customized, however, they pretty much function as a normal view.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.__accepted = False

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.__accepted = False # Use the normal serializer
    self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
    self.__accepted = True # Use the JobQueue serializer
    return self.create_accepted(request, *args, **kwargs)

def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_create(serializer)
    # Do not return a Response

def create_accepted(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = {}
    data['endpoint_name'] = request.data.get('name')
    # Add any data needed to create a JobQueue object.
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_create(serializer)
    data = serializer.data
    headers = self.get_success_headers(data)
    return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED,
                    headers=headers)

def get_serializer_class(self):
    serializer = None

    if self.__accepted:
        if self.request.version == Decimal("1"):
            serializer = JobQueueSerializerVer01
    else:
        if self.request.version == Decimal("1"):
            serializer = SomeSerializerVer01

    return serializer
```

Now the serializer changes:

```
class SomeSerializerVer01(serializers.Serializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # Call the task
        return wait_for_long_running_code.delay(
            validated_data, self.initial_data)

    def create_after_task(self, validated_data, initial_data):
        self.initial_data = initial_data
        self._create_or_update_job_queue(
            name, job_status=JobQueue.INPROGRESS)
        # Do what you need to do here
        data = {}

        # Update the JobQueue DB object.
        self._create_or_update_job_queue(
            name, job_status=JobQueue.SUCCESS,
            job_ended=datetime.datetime.now(tzutc()))

        return data

    def _create_or_update_job_queue(self, name, **kwargs):
        trx = JobQueue.objects.create_transaction(
            name, Endpoint.HOST_GROUP, self.get_user_object(), **kwargs)
        return trx
```

Now the task:

```
@shared_task(bind=True, default_retry_delay=15, max_retry=8)
def wait_for_long_runninf_code(self, validated_data, initial_data):
    from your.path import SomeSerializerVer01
    ser = SomeSerializerVer01()
    result = {}

    try:
       result = ser.create_after_task(validated_data, initial_data)
    except Exception:
       self.retry(exc=e)

    return result
```

And that's it. Some of what I do you may not need to do like passing the `initial_data` dict. Not everything is shown above, for example, the view and serializer for the `JobQueue` DB object.